# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when try to run flutter from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I downloaded my flutter project from GitHub. But it always gives error i.e "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". I have tried almost every solution i found on the internet. I also changed build system to legacy. Installed pods again update pods but found no solution. Still there after two days. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any luck? Have the exact same issue.

Comment: No luck, No help found :(

Answer (score 0):

After hours spent on resolving this problem I am giving solution that has worked in my case: run

```
`dart fix --apply`
```

in terminal to resolve all warnings, as recommended [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.0.0#your-code)